# Insert data from 1 column to many columns in another table (using 1 line) in sql

Tags: mysql, table

I have a table (table1) in which IDs of transactions, transaction state (there are 10 total states) and their time of entering that state are stored.

I want to feed this data into another table which would have 11 columns: 1 for the Transaction ID and the other 10 for the time that they enter each state.

I want to write this as an SQL query. I looked for it and found

```
insert into table2(ID, s1, s2, s3, s4 ... )
select ID, time from table1
where [];
```

but I don't have 10 different columns in table1 to copy from as there are 10 different rows corresponding to each ID and each state.

Please help me out in doing this is 1 query.

I am new to SQL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to "pivot".  Inform yourself about that type of query, and perhaps you will realize you can continue quite happily with just one table  in your application.

Comment: Please add your table schema and, if possible a sample data.

Comment: And please tag one DBMS only. Is it SQL-Server or MySQL?

Comment: Thanks for notifying. I am new to this server. It's mysql that I have to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard method to "pivot" data assuming the pair (id,state) is unique:

```
SELECT id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN state = 1 THEN `time` END) s1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN state = 2 THEN `time` END) s2,
       --     ..............................
       MAX(CASE WHEN state = 10 THEN `time` END) s10
FROM table1 
GROUP BY id;
```

That is solution for MySQL server.

Comment: Hi Akina - I ran your query in my fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6a82b387ce96c395c2e179f5927da80d) (see bottom of fiddle) - the result is wrong! 1 2018-05-22 09:00:00 null null
2 null 2018-05-22 09:00:00 null

Comment: @Vérace I use numbers for states. You use strings. And You mix up fieldnames. Modify values in CASE WHEN statements. They are to look like `CASE WHEN state_type = 'state_1' THEN transition_time END`. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d2916653dc5e66a6ca0a77279349035b

Comment: @Akina - maybe there's something I haven't understood - could you take a look [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/goh6RHduLsKD3xARUaC7xD/0)?

Comment: @Vérace Again You use `state_id` in CASEs instead of `state_type`.

Comment: Ah, yes - <Doh... slaps forehead> - stupidly used 1, 2, 3 for both type and id - <note to self - don't do this again!>. Thanks for taking the time to point that out!

Answer (score 1):

Find an example of a [pivot table here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table).

Comment: Pivoting technique was exactly what I was looking for but I didn't know the name. Thank You.

Comment: You could mark the answer as helpful if you found it so.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I did the following:

Created the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE state 
(
  state_id INTEGER, 
  state_type VARCHAR(10), 
  transition_time DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY (state_id, state_type)
);

CREATE TABLE summary 
(
  state_id INTEGER,
  s1_type_1 VARCHAR(10),
  s1_t1 DATETIME, 
  s1_type_2 VARCHAR(10),
  s2_t2 DATETIME, 
  s1_type_3 VARCHAR(10),
  s3_t3 DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY (state_id)
);
```

In my summary table, I've kept the state_type - this is not necessary for the final answer (you can just remove them from the query), but I left them in as it's easier to see how the answer was derived!

And then I created some sample data - I'm only using 3 columns, but the same principle applies to 10.

```
INSERT INTO state VALUES (1, 'state_1', '2018-05-22 07:00:00');
INSERT INTO state VALUES (1, 'state_2', '2018-05-22 08:00:00');
INSERT INTO state VALUES (1, 'state_3', '2018-05-22 09:00:00');
INSERT INTO state VALUES (2, 'state_1', '2018-05-22 07:00:00');
INSERT INTO state VALUES (2, 'state_2', '2018-05-22 08:00:00');
INSERT INTO state VALUES (2, 'state_3', '2018-05-22 09:00:00');
```

And then ran the following query.

```
INSERT INTO summary
SELECT s1.state_id, s1.state_type, s1.transition_time, s2.state_type, s2.transition_time, s3.state_type, s3.transition_time
FROM state s1
JOIN state s2 ON s1.state_id = s2.state_id
AND s1.state_type = 'state_1'
AND s2.state_type = 'state_2'
AND s2.transition_time = (SELECT transition_time FROM state WHERE state_id = s2.state_id AND state_type = 'state_2')
JOIN state s3 ON s1.state_id = s3.state_id
AND s1.state_type = 'state_1'
AND s3.state_type = 'state_3'
AND s3.transition_time = (SELECT transition_time FROM state WHERE state_id = s3.state_id AND state_type = 'state_3');
```

Result:

```
state_id state_type    transition_time  state_type     transition_time   state_type   transition_time       
       1    state_1 2018-05-22 07:00:00    state_2  2018-05-22 08:00:00   state_3   2018-05-22 09:00:00
       2    state_1 2018-05-22 07:00:00    state_2  2018-05-22 08:00:00   state_3   2018-05-22 09:00:00
```

This is all available in a fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7f2ed924219d9d56d56d3a1c416eae86). p.s.welcome to the forum!

Answer (score -1):

Please try below if something helpful

```
insert into table2(ID, s1, s2, s3, s4) 
select ID, time as t1, time as t2, time as t3, time as t4 
from table1 where [];
```

Comment: Now that is a good one, Kuldeep!